# Swiftの強制アンラップの解消方法

Tags: swift

コードの危険な部分をなくという問題で、Swiftの強制アンラップを解消したいのですが、どのように解消すれば良いのでしょうか？
例をあげれなくてすいません。

Comment: 強制アンラップを使用しないようにするためのコード例はいくらでもあげられますが、あなたのコードの中でどのように使用されているかがわからないと、どれを使用すべきかがお伝えできません。「例をあげれない」理由がなぜなのか分かりませんが、出来るだけ例を挙げてもらった方が良いでしょう。(何百もの方法があるわけでもないので、待っていれば何らかの回答は付くでしょうが…。)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ざっくり、次の3つを使い分けるのが、基本です。

1. Optional Chaining
2. Optional Binding
3. Nil-coalescing operator

---

*質問者さんの反応に応じて、それぞれの項目について、解説を書き加えていく用意があります。随時、コメント欄にリクエストをください。*

Comment: すいません。別の質問の方で回答をいただきました。ありがとうございました。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/68098/40856